# Ui_Component Grid in Admin tab

Tags: magento2, tabs, ui-form

I've created custom admin tab with layout form.

But i am failing to render grid in my created tab.

Below is my **Block** code where i would like to show products.

> ../Block/Adminhtml/Grid/Edit/Tab/Products.php

```
class Products extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template implements \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface
{

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    }

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('hello_tab_grid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {

        $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();

        $this->setCollection($collection);

        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('entity_id', [
                'header' => __('ID'),
                'sortable' => true,
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'type' => 'number',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn('title', [
                'header' => __('Sku'),
                'index' => 'sku',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-name',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-name'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn('position', [
                'header' => __('Position'),
                'name' => 'position',
                'width' => 60,
                'type' => 'number',
                'validate_class' => 'validate-number',
                'index' => 'position',
                'editable' => true,
            ]
        );

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRowUrl($item)
    {
        return '#';
    }

    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('Products');
    }

    /**
    * @return bool
    */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return $this->getTabLabel();
    }


    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }


    public function getTabUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('credit/grid/products');
    }

    /**
    * @return string
    */
    public function getTabClass()
    {
        return 'ajax only';
    }
 }
```

> ../Controller/Adminhtml/Grid/Products.php

```
class Products extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $resultLayoutFactory;

    public function __construct(
        LayoutFactory $resultLayoutFactory
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);

        $this->resultLayoutFactory = $resultLayoutFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultLayout->getLayout()->getBlock('grid.edit.tab.products');
        return $this->resultLayoutFactory->create();
    }
}
```

> ../adminhtml/credit_grid_products.xml

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
<container name="root" label="Root">
    <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Edit\Tab\Products" name="grid.edit.tab.products"/>
    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Serializer" name="grid_edit_tab_productsgrid_serializer">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="input_names" xsi:type="string">position</argument>
            <argument name="grid_block" xsi:type="string">grid.edit.tab.products</argument>
            <argument name="input_element_name" xsi:type="string">links[products]</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</container>
```

> ../adminhtml/layout/credit_grid_productsgrid.xml

```
<container name="root" label="Root">
    <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Edit\Tab\Products" name="grid.edit.tab.products"/>
</container>
```

Does any one has idea what's missing with this code ?

**`execute` method is working but grid isn't rendering**.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was used your code in .xhtml file but no luck

for render UI Componunt grid

my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

   <insertListing>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="autoRender" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="ns" xsi:type="string">event_record_list</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</insertListing>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `insertListing` to create grid under tab usi uiComponent (Magento 2.2)

```
<fieldset name="tab2">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">tab2</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <insertListing>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="autoRender" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="ns" xsi:type="string">ui_component_for_the_grid</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </insertListing>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Step 1 : Declare resource**

> app/code/Bannerslider/Banner/etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="Bannerslider_Banner_post_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Post\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<virtualType name="Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Post\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">Bannerslider_Banner_post</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Post</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

**Step 2 : Create layout file**

> app/code/Bannerslider/Banner/view/adminhtml/layout/Bannerslider_Banner_post_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<update handle="styles"/>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <uiComponent name="Bannerslider_Banner_post_listing"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

**Step 3 : Create component layout file**

> app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/view/adminhtml/ui_component/Bannerslider_Banner_post_listing.xml

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">Bannerslider_Banner_post_listing.Bannerslider_Banner_post_listing_data_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">Bannerslider_Banner_post_listing.Bannerslider_Banner_post_listing_data_source</item>
    </item>
    <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">spinner_columns</item>
    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Post</item>
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
<dataSource name="nameOfDataSource">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">Bannerslider_Banner_post_listing_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">post_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">post_id</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
<columns name="spinner_columns">
    <selectionsColumn name="ids">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">post_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </selectionsColumn>
    <column name="post_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="name">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="updated_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Modified</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
</columns>
```

For more information [Check here](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-admin-grid-magento-2.html)

Comment: Thanks for Responding But answer you provided is for grid, I already created it, Read question again, I need grid in tab.

Comment: It is possible, but for that you should have to use Form fieldset, may be it is not possible using UI Componet.